# Is there such data structure - "linked list with samples"

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Is there such data structure:

1. There is slow list data structure such `linked list` or `data saved on disk`.
2. There is relatively small array of pointers to some of the elements in the "slow list", hopefully evenly distributed.

Then when you do search, you first check the array and then perform the normal search (linked list search or binary search in case of disk data).

This looks very similar to `jump search`, `sample search` and to `skip lists`, but I think is different algorithm.

Please note I am giving example with `link list` or file on disk, because they are slow structures.

Comment: Are you looking for a data structure which exists as a library in a particular programming language, e.g. Java or C#?  Or is your question more general?  It seems you have already described the data structure in abstract terms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a name for this algorithm (I don't think it deserves one, though if there isn't, it could bear mine:), but I did implement something like that 10 years ago for an interview.

You can have an array of pointers to the elements of a list. An array of fixed size, say, of 256 pointers. When you construct the list or traverse it for the first time, you store pointers to its elements in the array. So, for a list of 256 or fewer elements you'd have a pointer to each element.

As the list grows beyond 256 elements, you drop every odd-numbered pointer by moving the 128 even-numbered pointers to the beginning of the array. When the array of pointers fills up again, you repeat the procedure. At every such point you double the step between the list elements whose addresses end up in the array of pointers. Initially you'd place every element's address there, then every other's, then of one out of four and so on.

You end up with an array of pointers to the list elements spaced apart by the list length / 256.

If the list is singly-linked, locating i-th element from the beginning or the end of it is reduced to searching in 1/256th of the list.
If the list is sorted, you can perform binary search on the array to locate the bin (the 1/256th portion of the list) where to look further.